# Why these two Cypher queries return different result?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to learn Cypher and I have the data of a [trust network](http://www.trustlet.org/downloaded_epinions.html), I wanted to query people who trust "15 most trusted people", so I wrote this query, QUERY1:

```
QUERY1:

MATCH (u1:USER)-[:TRUST]->(u2:USER) 
with u2.Id as id, COUNT(u2) AS score 
order by score desc
limit 15
match p=(w1:USER)-[:TRUST]->(w2:USER {Id: id})
return w1.Id as user1, w2.Id as user2
```

after that I wanted to change the last 2 lines of query to this:

```
QUERY2:

MATCH (u1:USER)-[:TRUST]->(u2:USER) 
with u2.Id as id, COUNT(u2) AS score 
order by score desc
limit 15
match p=(w1:USER)-[:TRUST]->(w2:USER {Id: id})-[:TRUST]->(w3:USER)
return w1.Id as user1,w2.Id as user2, w3.Id as user3
```

and after analyzing the result, I've guess that something is wrong!
so I hard coded `id` to specific value, for example 575, then `count(p)` is equal to 1937520, BUT if I run the last line of query with hardcoded Id, as a separate query:

```
QUERY3:

MATCH r=(u1:USER)-[:TRUST]->(u2:USER {Id: "575"})-[:TRUST]->(u3:USER)
return count(r)
```

the `count(r)` is equal to 129168!

I checked that the User "575" trust 207 people and is trusted by 624 people, so QUERY3 result seems correct: 207*624=129168. and my question is why?!
I can't understand what is wrong with the QUERY2, and the second question is does it mean that QUERY1 result is wrong too?

**EDIT1:**
thanks for answers, but I still had problem with this, so I checked another scenario and I've got the following result:
If I write a query like this:

```
QUERY4:
MATCH (n) WITH n limit 15 return "1"
```

I'll get 15 "1"s printed in the output, so it means the last part of QUERY2 executes 15 times, no matter if I hard code the Id or not, like it's in a for loop. so the problem here was that I thought the `WHIT X LIMIT N doSomeThing` would execute like a `foreach(x : X)` loop, if I use x, and would not, if I don't use x. stupid assumption...

Answer (score 1):

In QUERY3, you are matching u2 to a single user (user 575). QUERY 3 is correct.

However, in QUERY2, that WITH (line 3) matches 15 different u1-u2 combinations. The MATCH (line 1) returns a "row" for each u1 and u2 that..well, matches that pattern. Then you are returning just the first 15 results, which I guess are 15 different u1 for u2=user{Id:575} That´s what give 1937520 results, which is exactly 15 * 129168.

The problem in the with appears because you are not aggregating (not getting just 1 row for each u2). You 'return' (using WITH) one id variable for each u2 user, so count(u2) will always be 1. Maybe you wanted to write u1.Id or count(u1) ? Anyway, WITHing u2.Id or u1.Id will return 15 results because of the LIMIT 15 (line 4). LIMIT 1 would do the trick, but we can also do this:

```
MATCH (u1:User)-[:TRUST]-(u2:User)
WITH DISTINCT(u2.Id) AS id
LIMIT 15
```

And then the rest of the QUERY2 (or QUERY1, for that matter). I eliminated the score variable, but if it´s meant to be count(u1), it can be readded with no problem.

Comment: You're right, but if I change the (w2:USER {Id: id}) part of QUERY2 to (w2:USER {Id: "575"}) I get 1937520 result, does this mean that the last Match part runs 15 time for the USER "575", because of the limit 15?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the answer to reflect this. The problem was the lack of DISTINCT on the WITH, which caused the query to return many times the same user.

Answer (score 1):

This query might do what you intended.

```
MATCH (:USER)-[r:TRUST]->(u2:USER) 
WITH u2, COUNT(r) AS score 
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 15
MATCH (w1:USER)-[:TRUST]->(u2)-[:TRUST]->(w3:USER)
RETURN w1.Id AS user1, u2.Id AS user2, w3.Id AS user3;
```

It first finds the 15 most-trusted users, then finds all the 2-level trust paths that those users are in the middle of, and finally returns the ids of the users in those paths.

Also, the second `MATCH` reuses the `u2` nodes already found by the first `MATCH`, to speed up the processing of the second `MATCH`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just break down Query 2 and the rest should make sense.

```
QUERY2:

MATCH (u1:USER)-[:TRUST]->(u2:USER) 
with u2.Id as id, COUNT(u2) AS score 
order by score desc
limit 15
match p=(w1:USER)-[:TRUST]->(w2:USER {Id: id})-[:TRUST]->(w3:USER)
return w1.Id as user1,w2.Id as user2, w3.Id as user3
```

Starting with

```
MATCH (u1:USER)-[:TRUST]->(u2:USER) 
with u2.Id as id, COUNT(u2) AS score 
order by score desc
limit 15
```

You are basically creating a list of all u1 trusts u2; And COUNT(u2) = # of u2 matched. So assuming u1 trusts u2 has 100 matches, COUNT(u2) would put '100' in that column for each row. (and then you order on what is now a constant, which does nothing, and limit 15, so you now have an arbitrary list of 15 u1 trusts u2.

So that just leaves

```
match p=(w1:USER)-[:TRUST]->(w2:USER {Id: id})-[:TRUST]->(w3:USER)
```

So that is match each path p where a user w1 trusts user w2 (with for-each id from first part) who trusts a user w3.

So, fixing the first part, to get 'top 15 trusted users you need to count the number of incoming trusts

```
MATCH (u1:USER)-[trusts:TRUST]->(u2:USER) 
with u2, COUNT(trusts) AS score 
order by score desc
limit 15
```

So now you have 15 most trusted users and you can verify this with `return u2.id, score`. To get people who trust these people you would than just need to ask like...

```
MATCH (u3:USER)-[:TRUST]->(u2)
```

and u3 will then be all users who trust someone from top 15 trusted people (u2).

As an additional note, if you are using the neo4j web browser, try pre-pending the PROFILE keyword to your cypher for some insight into what the cypher query actually does.

Edit 1:

Now to explain what query 4 does `MATCH (n) WITH n limit 15 return "1"`. As I am sure you guessed, `MATCH (n) WITH n limit 15` matches all nodes but limits results to first 15. On the RETURN part, you are saying "For each row, return the constant '1'.", Which give you 15 distinct rows internally, but the returned rows are not distinct. This is what the DISTINCT keyword is for. Using RETURN DISTINCT "1" says "For each row, return the constant '1', but filter the result set to only have distinct rows." aka, no 2 columns will have the same value. The non-distinct result is useful if you know there will be some duplicate rows, but you want to see them anyways (maybe for a weight reference, or knowing that they are from 2 separate fields).

Comment: thanks, I learned so much thing from your answer, +1 for PROFILE keyword, but my problem was something else. I mentioned it in EDIT1.

Comment: @M-N not sure if Query 4 actually means anything to your problem, but I added an explanation of what Query 4 is doing so that you can understand the results. :3

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the EDIT1, the problem here was that I thought the `WHIT X LIMIT N doSomeThing` would execute like a `foreach(x : X)` loop, if I use x, and would not, if I don't use x. stupid assumption...